# How to pass Grails Command Object validation when a request is "GET"?

Tags: html, validation, grails, groovy, gsp

Hi I am new to Grails & Groovy.

Currently, I have a "Register" button on my homepage while it is linking to a controll "user" and action "register".

I have gsp view for user/register.

In my action of register I am using the command object to do some validation. (like password and confirm password check).

Here is the problem:

When I click the register button from my homepage, I think it then sends a "GET" request to "user/register".

```
<g:link controller="user" action="register">
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Join Free"/>
</g:link>
```

In my user controller I have this:

```
 def register(UserRegistrationCommand urc) {
    if (urc.hasErrors()) {
    render view: "register", model: [ user : urc ]
    } else {
    def user = new User(urc.properties)
    user.profile = new Profile(urc.properties)
    if (user.validate() && user.save()) {
    flash.message =
    "Welcome aboard, ${urc.fullName ?: urc.loginId}"
    redirect(uri: '/')
    } else {
    // maybe not unique loginId?
    return [ user : urc ]
    }
    }
    }
```

then this would trigger the logic in my register controller, which is the validation of the command object. However, after I click the button on the homepage, it is complaining about some fields like passowrd...etc. But I thought it should take me to the /user/register.gsp  first ? Then I can input registration details ?

Comment: Just wondering why are u using "GET" instead of "POST" ?

Comment: @emilan Thanks for replying, I just re-edit the question , hope it is clear for you?

Comment: Instead of `<g:link>` use `<g:submitButton>` or just a `button` to submit the form. I don't think that it's a good idea to send password in URL (GET).

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Use POST request for registration.

Second, use a CO that matches with your registration data. Means don't use extra properties that are not required for you while registering. Or modify your constraints.

Validation happens if you call validate method or during save. You can bypass validation by calling `save(validation: false)` But you should not do that.

Comment: Thanks for replying first. I think I confused you. My issue here is, I have a link from a button "Register" at my homepage taking me to the register controller. However, after I click it from my homepage, it is not showing the register.gsp view first. Instead, it is complaining about field password is null ...etc. I assume, when I click the register button from my homepage, it would send a "GET" method to user/register controller? Then for somehow, the object validation is triggered at the same time. Therefore, I am not seeing the webpage but validation errors

Comment: You should use two different actions. First one to render gsp page for registration only and second one to submit the data when after user fills in the data

Comment: That's what I am thinking... god I am following those books (GrailsInAction), but they all are like the example I pasted here. How come were they working then... Thanks again!